# How can I do group commenting without commenting each line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How can I comment a group of lines without commenting each line?

I.e., like in [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29):

```
/*
printf("hello");
printf("there");
*/
```

In MATLAB, the only way I know to do this is to comment each line:

```
%disp('hello')
%disp('there')
```

I have a 100 lines to comment out, and I would prefer to group comment it like in C.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Can I comment a block of lines in an MATLAB file using /* ... */ as I can in C?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-17Y20/?solution=1-17Y20%20an%20I%20comment%20a%20block%20of%20lines%20in%20an%20MATLAB%20file%20using%20/%2a%20...%20%2a/%20as%20I%20can%20in%20C?):

```
%{
...
Block of COMMENTS HERE
...
...
%}
%CODE GOES HERE
plot(1:10)
```

Answer (score 6):

1. MATLAB v7+:

   ```
    %{
    ...code to be commented
    %}
   ```
2. Use the editor:

   Select all the lines, and then choose toggle comment or something in the menu. It's there.

Comment: Or just use the Ctrl+R/Ctrl+T shortcuts :)

Comment: not working for me, command+T opens a new tab, and command+R restarts the kernel.

Comment: What menu? The "Text" menu? In what environment? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15980450/edit) a screenshot? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Or just select the group of lines you want to comment, and then use keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (forward slash)'.

And voila, it will comment each line in the selected block with `%` as one would do individually.

To undo, I tried, but I don't know what key stroke can work.

Answer (score 0):

Select all lines and then do:

For commenting:

From the *Text* menu → *Comment*

For uncommenting:

From the *Text* menu → *Uncomment*

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboard shortcuts:

To comment multiple lines: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

To uncomment multiple lines: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

It works perfect in MATLAB 2016.